# align single lines in \split

Tags: equations, alignment, split

[image]I have 3 equations and their names within a single \equation\split setting and want to leftalign their names but keep the alignment for everything else.
Tried doing it myself with \raggedleft and re-centering but that just created chaos. How do i do it properly?
`\begin{equation} \label{Gl2} \begin{split} & \textbf{ab} \\& a=b \\& \textbf{bc} \\& b=c \\& \textbf{cd} \\& c=d     \end{split} \end{equation}`

Comment: Welcome! Can you please show a sketch of what you'd like to get?

Comment: @egreg sure, one second

Comment: so the ab, bc, cd with an arrow are supposed to be aligned to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy (which usually means it's not a good idea )

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation*}
\stepcounter{equation}
\sbox0{(\theequation)}
\hspace{0pt}
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd0\relax}
\vspace*{-\abovedisplayskip}
\begin{align*}
\shortintertext{\textbf{ab}}
\quad a &= b \\
\shortintertext{\textbf{bc}}
\quad b &= c \\
\shortintertext{\textbf{cd}}
\quad c &= d
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\tag{\theequation}
\end{equation*}
X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\text{check the number}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: im open to better ideas but i need it in a single equation environment  so i basically have to build the whole box right? any specific reason to use equation* instead of equation*? and thanks for your answer

Comment: @MarcelDavis I used `equation*` and `\tag` because with `equation` it doesn’t work. As for “better ideas”, a real world example would be needed.